# Ripple effect not present in Recyclerview?

Tags: android

I can't get my recycler view items to have the "Ripple effect" when clicked, like this:

[image]

I found a lot of similar questions on Stackoverflow, but I did not find anything that helped.

Here is my whole layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/start_root_view"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/topContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="24dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/image_card"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="32dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/user_image"
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp" />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/welcome_message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Welcome back!"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_card"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/username_display"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username_display"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="username"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_card"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/welcome_message"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_questions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topContainer"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_add_question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccentDark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I should also state that I have added both a ItemTouchHelper and RecyclerView.ItemDecoration to my Recyclerview from my Activity code.

I don't understand why the effect is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

with:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

And that attribute needs to be on the element that is supposed to ripple. Right now, you have the `android:foreground` on the `ConstraintLayout` that appears to be the entire fragment or activity. If you want rows (or cells or whatever) in a `RecyclerView` to ripple, you need `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` on the layouts for those rows/cells/whatever.

For example, see [this resource](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/blob/v0.3/ActionBar/src/main/res/layout/row.xml) in [this sample module](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/tree/v0.3/ActionBar) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I tried this earlier, it still does not get the ripple effect to work?

Comment: I think that either my ItemTouchHelper or RecyclerView.ItemDecoration might be the culprit, but I can't figure it out?

Comment: @Carlton: If you are intercepting touch events, that might interfere with the selectable background, so try commenting out the `ItemTouchHelper`.

Comment: I tried commenting out both/either ItemDecoration and ItemTouchHelper, but the ripple effect is still now showing. I don't understand it. Do you know of any other ideas I could try?

Comment: @Carlton: Any children of that root `ConstraintLayout` that consume touch events will also block the ripple. You applied that `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` to the root `ConstraintLayout`, so any touch events in the `RecyclerView` will not reach it. If you are expecting the rows (or whatever) in that `RecyclerView` to ripple, you need `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` on *those* layouts, for whatever adapter/viewholder you are using with that `RecyclerView`.

Comment: That is correct. I had to add that to the rootview of my item layout, and the ripple effect is working properly. Could you post your latest comment as an answer so I could accept the answer for future readers of same problem? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Carlton: Done! And I'm glad that you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

If you want your recyclerview rows to have ripple effect, you should use selectableItemBackground attribute in your recyclerviews row layout file.

The attribute should be set to whichever view is consuming the click event.